# Incompatible type error with Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c

> ```
> Sending 'ForsteSettFasitViewController *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<UIScrollViewDelegate>'
> ```

here is the line where I get the semantic issue:

```
[scrollerForstFasit setDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 3):

You left out a very important part of the warning. After `id`, you should see a named protocol, something like `id<SomeKindOfDelegate>`. Either way, you're receiving this error, because you're assigning self as the delegate, but you never specified that the class should conform to the protocol.

```
@interface MySubclass : MyBaseClass <TheSameDelegateFromBefore>
```

Now that you've pasted the full error. It should be the following

```
@interface MySubclass : MyBaseClass <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `scrollerForstFasit` is a subview of `UIScrollView`, its delegate must conform to the `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` protocol. Make sure your `self` (whatever class it is) conforms to this protocol before setting it as the delegate. You can do this in your .h

```
@interface MyClassThatICallSelfAndAssignAsDelegate : MySuperclass <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be selve in two ways either in your .h fil add

```
@interface YourClass : YourBaseClass<UIScrollViewDelegate>
@end
```

or in your.m file

```
@interface YourClass ()<UIScrollViewDelegate>
@end
```

The error/warning is because you are not conforming  in your class and trying to set the object as a scrollview's delegate